# Response returns null data because query takes time as it is executing multiple times in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Route.js

```
router.post('/social/google', auth, async (req, res, next) => {
try {
 let social = await socialHandler.addSocial(req.body, req.userData.id)
 let googleToken = await socialHandler.getSocial(req.userData.id)
 let googleData = await socialHelper.googleToken(googleToken.google_access_token)
 var nameArray = googleData.connections
 let result;
 let promises = [];


nameArray.map(async (element) => {
  console.log('element')
  console.log(element)
  if (element.emailAddresses || element.phone_number) {
    promises.push(await socialHandler.getUser(emailAddresses[0].value, 
    phoneNumbers[0].canonicalForm));  ===>> It takes long time to execute as it run multiple time so it execute after response

  }  
  let obj = {
    id: (element.names && element.names[0].metadata.source.id) ? element.names[0].metadata.source.id : '',
    name: (element.names && element.names[0].displayName) ? element.names[0].displayName : '',
    email: element.emailAddresses ? element.emailAddresses[0].value : '',
    phone_number: element.phoneNumbers ? element.phoneNumbers[0].canonicalForm : '',
    common: ''
  }
  promises.push(obj)
  console.log(promises)
  result = await Promise.all(promises);
})
req.data = promises ==> It returns null
req.status = 200
req.message = 'Google Contacts Fetched Succcessfully'
next()

}
```

I check socialHandler.getUser if user is saved or not. It works properly but what issue I got query can run n number of times depends on how many users are there. Query is taking time so it returns result null and after it returns query runs . Can someone help me out . I have tried async await also but await does not works

Comment: `Array.prototype.map` does not support async/await. Therefore all the code inside `map` is executed after `req.data = promises`. None of the Array functions support async/await. You cannot use map or forEach or filter or reduce. Replace it with a for loop or a while loop.

Comment: Yes it works with for loop thanks man